# Removing constant results in constant still being available

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.5

Check that `Object` constant is defined

```
Module.const_defined?('Object')
#=> true
```

Remove the constant

```
Object.send(:remove_const, 'Object')
#=> Object
```

Check, that `Object` constant is removed

```
Module.const_defined?('Object')
#=> false
```

Now, how do the following examples return the `Object` constant if it is removed? :)

```
String.superclass
#=> Object
new_object = String.superclass.new
#=> #<Object:0x00007fdc18382858>
new_object.class
#=> Object
```

Comment: Have you tried this with something a little less special than `Object` and `String`?

Comment: @muistooshort tbh I didn't. But I now do not think it *should* make any difference with anything less special, because constant is a constant. Why would different constants behave differently?

Comment: Because `Object` and `String` aren't just any old constants, they're features of the language itself. You can't say `'Object'` without interacting with the `String` class (and hence `Object`), you can't say `Module` without interacting with `Object`, you can't call a method without interacting with `Object` in various ways (via `Method` and `Symbol` at least). If you don't have `Object` then you don't have Ruby. You're attempting to reason from a very special specific case, might be better to start with a more general case.

Comment: The doc for [Module#remove_const](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-remove_const) states, "Removes the definition of the given constant, returning that constant's previous value. If that constant referred to a module, this will not change that module's name and can lead to confusion." More fundamentally, could you imagine Matz permitting users to remove the class `Object` (or `BassicObject`)? What purpose could that conceivably serve? Note the proviso refers to all modules, including custom ones. As an aside, I think the doc could be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, how do the following examples return the `Object` constant if it is removed?

They don't. They *can't*. Constants aren't objects in Ruby, therefore, they *cannot possibly* return the `::Object` constant.

They *can*, however, return an object which responds to `inspect` with the string `'Object'`. An object, which happens to be the same object which used to be referenced by the now-removed `::Object` constant.

Removing the constant removes the constant. Nothing more. In particular, it *does not* delete the object that is referenced by the constant. **IFF** that constant was the *only* reference to that object, **THEN** that object will now be eligible for garbage collection. But that is not the case here: the `::Object` constant is not the only reference to the `Object` class, since every subclass of the `Object` class has a reference to the `Object` class in its `superclass` pointer and every instance of the `Object` class has a reference to the `Object` class in its `class` pointer. Plus, internal data structures of the execution engine may or may not have references to the `Object` class.

Therefore, the `Object` class will pretty much never get garbage collected, and you will always have some reference to it, through which you can access it, e.g. `''.class.superclass` will give you access to the `Object` class regardless of whether or not the `::Object` constant still exists.

In short: you are confusing the constant `::Object` with the object that is referenced by this constant. This is a common beginner mistake. However, the distinction between the name of a thing and the thing itself is *fundamental* in almost all programming languages.

Comment: `inspect` makes perfect sense, thank you. Side question:  what is constant since it is not an object?

Comment: It's a language construct just like syntax, `if` expressions, method `def`initions etc. This is not something that is peculiar to Ruby: variables aren't objects / values in almost all programming languages and certainly in all mainstream languages. In fact, in most languages (not just programming languages but natural languages as well), the distinction between a thing and a name of a thing is *fundamental*.